# Is there a way to simply unit test Sirikit intent extension implementations?

Tags: swift, unit-testing, swift-extensions, sirikit

I don't seem to find a way to easily add unit tests to Sirikit extension.

I would like to be able to test Siri implementation in my app with some unit test to be able to assure myself of non regression with the evolution of the feature but I can't find a good and simple way to unit test all the code of the extension.

If any of you have some good examples or tutorials on how to implement this or any tips on the subject, It would be very welcome.

Comment: have a look at this article [SiriKit Part 3](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/sirikit-part-3-finishing-touches/)

Comment: @chirag90: Thank you for the tip but it doesn't really answer my question. The test they seems to be doing are UI tests. What I would like to do is unit tests of an extension.